$\int_{[0,t]} |f(s)| \, ds \leq \int_{[0,\infty]}e^{M(t-s)} \operatorname{sup}_{s\geq 0} |f(s)|e^{-Ms} \, ds $? Measure theory inequality

For any Lebesgue measurable function $f$, and $M>0$, if $\operatorname{sup}_{s\geq 0}|f(s)|e^{-Ms}<\infty$. I wonder if the following inequality hold $$\int_{[0,t]} |f(s)| \, ds \leq \int_{[0,\infty]}e^{M(t-s)} \operatorname{sup}_{s\geq 0} [|f(s)|e^{-Ms}] \, ds $$

I tried to drop the supremum, and lower bound $e^{M(t-s)}$ by $1_{[0,t]}$ but the term $e^{-Ms}$ at the end seems to be difficult to deal with. So I'm not sure if this inequality holds.
Feel free to assume $f$ is continuous. This arises in some proof of showing a Lipschitz like property.

If the supremum is denoted by $C$, then RHS is just $C\int_0^{\infty} e^{M(t-s)}ds=C\frac {e^{Mt}} M$.
LHS $\le \int_0^{t} Ce^{Ms}ds=C\frac {e^{Mt}-1} M<C\frac {e^{Mt}} M$.

Thank you, but I don’t understand the first inequality after LHS, what if the supremum is achieved at $3t$ for instance

$|f(s)|e^{-Ms} \le C$ for all $s \ge 0$, in particular for $0 \le s \le t$.  @wsz_fantasy

@wsz_fantasy $$\int_0^t\lvert f(s)\rvert,\mathrm{d}s=\int_0^t \underbrace{\lvert f(s)\rvert e^{-Ms}}_{\leq C}e^{Ms},\mathrm{d}s\leq\int_0^t Ce^{Ms},\mathrm{d}s$$
